# Не запускает скрипт, а код в браузере

Tags: php

Всем привет, создал я файл index.php, настрочил что-то, но как открываю файл - в браузере вижу только код. Раньше такого не было, в чем проблема? При чем код любой, даже обычный echo

Comment: у вас в апаче (или что вы там используете) не настроена обработка файлов с разширение php интерпретатором php

Answer (score 0):

PHP выполняется на сервере. Если Вы видите код PHP значит сервер не обрабатывает PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Вы внутри вашего файла забыли написать инструкция для компилятора, что это php.

Напишите ваш код вот так

```
<?php

    echo "Привет мир!";

?>
```